# How can I update Pyspark dataframe's column according to similarities with another dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, similarity

I am working with 2 dataframes, let's say 'df1' and 'df2', which are the next kind:

df1:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Col1  |  Col2  |
+--------+--------+
|  'A'   |  1     |
+--------+--------+
|  'B'   |  2     |
+--------+--------+
|  'C'   |  3     |
+--------+--------+
```

df2:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Col1  |  Col2  |
+--------+--------+
|  'A'   |  -     |
+--------+--------+
|  'B'   |  -     |
+--------+--------+
|  'B'   |  -     |
+--------+--------+
```

What I want to do is to update column 'Col2' of 'df2' taking into account the values of 'df1'. I mean, I want to set the values of 'df2' 'Col2' with values of 'df1' Col2' according to the reference with the value of 'Col1'.

The resulting dataframe 'df2' should be:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Col1  |  Col2  |
+--------+--------+
|  'A'   |  1     |
+--------+--------+
|  'B'   |  2     |
+--------+--------+
|  'B'   |  2     |
+--------+--------+
```

How can I do it with pyspark dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join should do,

```
df2.join(df1,df1.col1==df2.col1,'left')
```